# R: how to download the zip binaries and all the dependencies of a list of packages for an offline installation on another machine?

Tags: r, rstudio, cran

I am using `R 3.3.1` and the latest version of `R studio` on a computer behind a firewall.

I would like to know how I can download all the `zip binaries` (not the sources, because I cannot compile them) for the packages I need (`dplyr`, `plm`, etc) **AND their dependencies** on my home computer, so that I can export them to the machine under firewall and just install them offline.

How can I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: If you install the packages, all the files are in your library (see `.libPaths`). You can zip up the folder and restore into the library on the other machine.

Comment: just copy and pasting everything? how can I find the right path where to put the unzipped data?

Comment: Once you install R, in the target machine's library (from running `.libPaths`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Packrat R package; it has a `bundle` method which packs up all the packages (and their dependencies), and an `unbundle` method which unpacks them onto the target machine. They go into a private library, too, so they won't stomp on other libraries on your machine.

More here: https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/

Once you've installed Packrat, type `?packrat::bundle` for further instructions.

Comment: thanks jonathan, so for a concrete example (sorry for my noobiness here) say I am insterested in `dplyr and `plm`, what should be the correct syntax with packra?

Comment: also @Jonathan, does packat merely collects the `sources` or the `binaries`?

Comment: you don't need to specify those explicitly; Packrat looks at all the code in the current directory and automatically determines what packages are needed (so just put all the code you want to work with in a folder and include it with the bundle)

Comment: it collects sources and binaries; there's an argument to `bundle` which allows the binary library to be included in the bundle.